How to return the value of the last non-blank cell in a row? And the average of the last three?
I'm new here, so it's highly probable I am making some mistakes in the way I am formulating my issue. Didn't find answers fully related to my problem, unfortunately. Thanks a lot for your help in advance :)
I'm looking to track my progress on some key life projects, and along these lines, I would like to be able to put each month a value containing my assessment of where things stand (a score between 1-10).
I would also love to have a percentage showing the progress (or regress) over the last 3/6/12 months and use the TREND function to show a forecasted value in 3/6/12 months.
Table (in the table, none of the past and future trends columns have correct numbers. The purpose of my message is to try to work out a proper formula)
I tried the formula =INDEX(P23:BW23,COUNT(P23:BW23)) where "P23 to BW23" is the row I'm focused on, but since there will be blanks for some months, I will have a problem in the future. Besides, I can retrieve the value of the cell, but not the cell itself.
I also tried =LOOKUP(9999999999, (P23:BW23)). This one works very well, but then I tried to get an average of the three months before and tried this:
=AVERAGE((LOOKUP(9999999999, (P23:BW23))-3):LOOKUP(9999999999, (P23:BW23)))
It didn't work. I do realize it must be very mistaken (and quite ridiculous), but I can't quite figure out how to write the correct syntax.
I hope you can help me out. Thank you so much for your kind help ;)
Link to Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dImqvTn14xSY9EXaV-mho1b4cv2b-h1nqzcaWoqmbyU/edit?usp=sharing

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Does this answer your question? How to take the last non-blank value in a column

It is true that you need well defined input and desired output in your question that do not leave room for ambiguity and guesswork. For example, whether you are detecting last non-blank cell of the whole column vs last non-blank cell of a block of non-blank cells will have different solutions. Separately, similar questions have been asked numerous times in the past, including the one I linked. Could you clarify how your question is different?

Hello Rockinfreakshow and Argyll ;) Thank you so much for your quick replies. I have made a sheet from the suggested tool here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dImqvTn14xSY9EXaV-mho1b4cv2b-h1nqzcaWoqmbyU/edit?usp=sharing

With regard to your questions, let's assume it is October 24, I would love to have a sense of progress in a period of 3/6/12 months even if I forgot to input some values during specific months. I assume that a percentage is ideal. For future forecasts, I think that the TREND formula is straightforward to use. But I would still need a way to capture the 3/6/12 last values that aren't blanks.
My apologies if it is a bit cryptic. I'm excited to try my hand at spreadsheets, but there is a steep learning curve.

The reason why I think the other answer can't fully help me is dual. First, it is related to columns when I need an idea on how to deal with a row. And second, because the answer just focuses on the last value, when I would love to determine a trend out of the 3/6/12 last values.


Here's one possible solution for last 3 non-blank numbers average:
=let(Σ,torow(I6:W6,1),x,columns(Σ),round(average(choosecols(Σ,if(x<3,sequence(1,x),{-3,-2,-1}))),2))


